# jQuery Storing Element in a Variable

Tags: jquery

I have the code below which when a list item is clicked an animation occurs.

What I'm having trouble with is making the list item when clicked again reverse the animation effect.

I'm trying to store the clicked list item in a variable but having trouble with this as my variable never stores the elements details?

There may be a better way of doing this but any help or advice would be great?

```
 <ul class="circles">
     <li class="c-1"><div class="c-1-active">Text Link</div></li>
     <li class="c-2"><div class="c-1-active">Text Link</div></li>
     <li class="c-3"><div class="c-1-active">Text Link</div></li>
  </ul>



$('#home ul.circles li').click(function() {
    alert(testing);
    if(testing > "" || testing == $(this).find('div'))
    {
        testing.animate({opacity: 0, top:'180px'}, 1000 );
    }
        $(this).find('div').animate({opacity: 0.8, top:'0'}, 1000 );
        var testing = $(this).find('div');

});
```

Comment: Add some class when its in one state, check using hasClass and do acordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [**toggle**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) function:

```
$('#home ul.circles li').toggle(function() {
    $(this).find('div').stop().animate({opacity: 0, top:'180px'}, 1000 );
},function() {
    $(this).find('div').stop().animate({opacity: 0.8, top:'0'}, 1000 )
});
```

**UPDATE:** According to your comment, this solution should be more preferable:

```
$('#home ul.circles li').click((function(){
    var prevElement = null;
    return function(){            
        //Hiding previously active element
        prevElement && $(prevElement).stop().animate({opacity: 0, top:'180px'}, 1000);

        var curElement = $(this).find('div').get(0);
        $(curElement).stop().animate({opacity: 0.8, top:'0'}, 1000);
        prevElement = curElement;
    };
})());
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The Toggle works well and shows and hides the div when a specific list item is clicked. Is there a way to close any of the other list items if their div is currently active?

Answer (score 2):

The problem, why the variable never is recalled is, because you define a new variable within the scope of the "on click" event handler. What you could do, is this:

Add this line in <del>the global scope</del> an enclosing `closure` like `$.ready()`:

```
var testing = null;
```

And replace this line:

```
 var testing = $(this).find('div');
```

with this:

```
 testing = $(this).find('div');
```

But as stated in the comments, you should use a class to give an element a state. And than you can use functions like **.toggleClass()** to change the state easily.

**EDIT**

As requested in the comments, that only one will ever have the "active" state, this would be a simple solution:

JavaScript:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    var circles = $('#home ul.circles li');
    var current = 0;

    circles.click( function(event) {

        var position    = circles.index( $(event.target).parent() );

        if ( current != position ) {

            circles.eq(current).animate( { opacity: 0.5 }, 1000 );  
            current = position;
            circles.eq(current).animate( { opacity: 1 }, 1000 );
        }

        event.preventDefault();

    });

});

</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style>

    #home ul.circles > li {
        opacity:        0.5;
    }

    #home ul.circles > li.c-1 {
        opacity:        1.0;
    }

</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="home">
    <ul class="circles">
        <li class="c-1"><div class="c-1-active">Text Link</div></li>
        <li class="c-2"><div class="c-1-active">Text Link</div></li>
        <li class="c-3"><div class="c-1-active">Text Link</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I vote no on the `global scope`, yes to an enclosing `closure` such as a `$.ready()`.

Comment: Point taken and one up for talking me into senses. :). I'll change this (as I only wanted to demonstrate, why it's not working, and didn't want to force somebody to use the global space for something like this).

Comment: Thanks for your help that works nicely. Think I'll take a look at using Toggle as well if that is a better method?

Comment: It depends a bit of what you want to achieve in the end. If you don't need the current state somewhere else, you're fine with `.toggle()`. If you want to recall the state later, you can store it in a variable (like you did) or in a class (like @lovedager did) or even within the jQuery object itself using `.data()`. There are a lot of different approaches.

Comment: I ideally want to only ever have one active state at any one time. So clicking another list item would close all other active states and makes this active.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add a class of `clicked`

This should work well:

```
$('#home ul.circles li').click(function() {
    alert(testing);
    if($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
        $(this).find('div').animate({opacity: 0, top:'180px'}, 1000 );
        $(this).removeClass('clicked');
    } else {
        $(this).find('div').animate({opacity: 0.8, top:'0'}, 1000 );
        $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that works but I need to close any other list items with a class of clicked as well?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That still doesn't close any other open clicked classes. I belive it's cause it's checking the current clicked list item rather than all the list items that are within #home ul.circles li ?